# creating textbox from list in flutter

Tags: flutter, textbox

I have List like this (It keeps changing because this is the response of API,

```
tableValue=[
      {
        "id": "RegNo",
        "displayName": "Enter Register No",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "1XYZ19AA"
      },
      {
        "id": "name",
        "displayName": "Enter Name",
        "type": "string",
        "value": "KARAN"
      },
      {
        "id": "sub",
        "displayName": "choose subjects",
        "type": "list",
        "value": ["JAVA"],
        "data": [
          {"id": "1", "dispId": "JAVA"},
          {"id": "2", "dispId": "Python"},
          {"id": "3", "dispId": "Dart"}
        ]
      }
    ];
```

What I want to display is like below,

Based on the List, I want to display all its data,
i.e

```
Enter Register No --Text_Box here--
Enter Name        --Text_Box here--
```

(How many entries have string type I want to display a text box with its display name and a value defined in the List for that map should be displayed example 1XYZ19AA on the textbox),
If there are n entries with the type string n text box with the display name should be displayed, and I want to have the control over the data entered.
If there are 3 text boxes in the list if the user enters all or only 1 I should be able to access that uniquely.

**Question**

> Can you suggest any way of displaying if its a type list, because elements in a list should have a multi-select option?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: tableValue.length,
  itemBuilder:(context, index){
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/10,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/10,
             alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
             child:Text(tableValue[index]['displayName'])
           ),
          Container(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/10,
             alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerStart,
             child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                  hintText: "blah"
                )
             )
           )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where you can show the data from the table and also you can see how to access the selected values of the TextFields and Checkboxs

Note that you may need to change the type of tableValue like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> tableValue = [...]
Map<String, TextEditingController> controllers = {};
Set<String> checks = {};
```

This would be the body of your screen

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: tableValue
          .where((entry) => entry["type"] == "string")
          .map((entry) => Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(entry["displayName"]),
                  Flexible(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: getController(entry["id"]),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )).toList(),
    ),
    Column(
      children: tableValue
          .firstWhere(
              (entry) => entry["type"] == "list")["data"]
          .map<Widget>(
            (data) => CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(data["dispId"]),
              value: checks.contains(data["id"]),
              onChanged: (checked) {
                setState(() {
                  checked ? checks.add(data["id"]) : checks.remove(data["id"]);
                });
              },
            ),
          ).toList(),
    ),
    Text("Texts: ${controllers.values.map((controller) => controller.text)}"),
    Text("Checks: ${checks.map((check) => check)}"),
  ],
)
```

And this is how you could handle the TextField controllers

```
TextEditingController getController(String id) {
  controllers.putIfAbsent(id, () => TextEditingController());
  return controllers[id];
}
```